# When suggesting edits, don't write something you are not doing like "improving formatting"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Apparently some users have abused the "improving formatting" comment for their suggested edits and use them for anything... ANYTHING, even if it's not improving formatting. I remember that when suggesting edits my Firefox has 300 different reasons stored in the autocomplete... heck, someone once gave me a nug because my description where a bit colorful. Now, when describing your edits put something like:

- fixing grammar, improving formatting.
- fixing typos, improved links
- added image from comments
- added information from comments and imported pastebin link content

Remember that the more verbose you are the faster the reviewers can decide if your suggestion was good, bad or lacking and approve or reject accordingly.

Comment: Do you think my edit reasons are fine? I want to avoid a finger hernia :)